# networkStatsManager return 0 if default sim is diffrent than sim we are using for data consuming

Tags: android

I am using this method for track data usage

```
networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, subscriberID, start, end, uid);
```

it's returning `0` if default sim is different than sim we are using for data consuming.